# Delivering images via HTTPS protocol using {image}?

Tags: channel-images, secure

I am using ExpressionEngine for an e-commerce site and it is using the HTTPS protocol site-wide. HTTPS is failing on my homepage because the images are being delivered(using `{image}`) from the HTTP protocol. I am wondering how I can tell ExpressionEngine to deliver these images via HTTPS instead.

Any help greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using relative paths in your upload preferences.

Comment: I didn't even think about changing the Upload Preferences, I just figured EE was using "Root URL" from general configuration as the prefix. Changed the path in Upload Preferences and the images are being delivered via HTTPS now, thanks!